# How do I set the defaults (Language & Keyboard) for an Android AVD (SDK 2.1 & 2.2)

Tags: android

I recently upgraded to Android SDK 2.1 and 2.2 but the AVD always displays with Chinese and Japanese characters active. I can go to Settings to uncheck these options but it's becoming a pain. How can I set the Language & Keyboard defaults to avoid this hassle?

Thanks ...

Comment: You only need to make that change once per AVD, or until you wipe the user settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonsWare's comment is the answer: You only need to make that change once per AVD, or until you wipe the user settings.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But I was hoping there was a way of doing it at the creation of the AVD. Thanks anyway ...

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to set it in the AVD either. boourns. Maybe it'll be fixed in a later version.