# How do I get rid of the Chinese and Japanese characters on my AVD 2.1/2.2 Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can anyone tell me how to change the Language & Keyboard start-up settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the defaults (Language & Keyboard) for an Android AVD (SDK 2.1 & 2.2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088722/how-do-i-set-the-defaults-language-keyboard-for-an-android-avd-sdk-2-1-2-2)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings, Locale & Keyboard and you will find there some option to turn of **IME**

Comment: Thanks, I know that. What I'm trying to do is set a default such that I don't have to do that every time I run a test!